# AngularJS typed info in one input made ng-repeat shows in all input boxes

Tags: angularjs

I am having an issue where when I enter enter a piece of information in one comment input field it shows up in all the input fields. It still only submits to the one post, but since more than one comment input field is usually visible at a time it is jarring. Here is the angularJS that I am using:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in $ctrl.posts | orderBy: sortData | filter: {title: searchBox}" class="well">
<div class="media-left">
<img ng-src='{{post.image}}' class="media-object">
</div>
<div class="media-body">
<h4 class="media-heading">
              {{post.title}}
              |
<a ng-click='$ctrl.upVote(post)'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i></a>
<a ng-click='$ctrl.downVote(post)'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i></a>
              {{post.votes}}
</h4>
<div class="text-right">
  {{post.author}}
</div>
<p>
  {{post.body}}
</p>
<div>
 <div am-time-ago='post.createdOn'></div>
  |
 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
 <a ng-click='model.comment=$index'>
 <ng-pluralize count="post.comments.length" when="{'0': 'No comments.',
                   '1': '1 comment.',
                   'other': '{} comments.'}">
  </ng-pluralize>
  </a>
  <div class="comment" ng-show='model.comment==$index'>
  <ul ng-repeat='comment in post.comments'>
  <li>{{comment.text}}</li>
  </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-offset-1">
    <hr>
    <p>
      Comment text
    </p>
    <form class="form-inline" ng-submit='$ctrl.addComment(post)'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" ng-model='$ctrl.commentText'>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The input line in question is `<input class="form-control" ng-model='$ctrl.commentText'>`

Comment: almost solved. the input-fields need separate ng-models.

Answer (score 0):

you need separate models for the comment on each post. they were sharing `$ctrl.comment` and thats why typing in one reflected in the other.

i've used `post.comment` in the snippet cause it was a quick win to implement, but you could also be an array/hash where you use

- the index of the ng-repeat or
- a unique identifier of the post object as the key/index.

```js
angular.module('commentApp', [])
.controller('CommentController', commentControllerFn);

function commentControllerFn() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.posts = [{
    title: 'wyd?',
    author: 'GRISHAM',
    body: 'this doesnt make sense',
    comments: []
  },
  {
    title: 'This is the way',
    author: 'sage',
    body: 'read my post pls',
    comments: []
  }];
  
  vm.addComment = function(post){
    post.comments.push({
      text: post.commentText
    });
  }
  
  return this;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="commentApp">
  <div ng-controller="CommentController as ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="post in ctrl.posts | orderBy: sortData | filter: {title: searchBox}" class="well">
      <div class="media-left">
        <img ng-src='{{post.image}}' class="media-object">
      </div>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h4 class="media-heading">
          {{post.title}} |
          <a ng-click='ctrl.upVote(post)'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></i></a>
          <a ng-click='ctrl.downVote(post)'><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"></i></a> {{post.votes}}
        </h4>
        <div class="text-right">
          {{post.author}}
        </div>
        <p>
          {{post.body}}
        </p>
        <div>
          <div am-time-ago='post.createdOn'></div>
          |
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></i>
          <a ng-click='model.comment=$index'>
            <ng-pluralize count="post.comments.length" when="{'0': 'No comments.',
                   '1': '1 comment.',
                   'other': '{} comments.'}">
            </ng-pluralize>
          </a>
          <div class="comment" ng-show='model.comment==$index'>
            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat='comment in post.comments'>{{comment.text}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-offset-1">
            <hr>
            <p>
              Comment text
            </p>
            <form class="form-inline" ng-submit='ctrl.addComment(post)'>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model='post.commentText'>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```